# Accessing calendars with EventKit on pyobjc (trouble passing entityType)

Tags: eventkit, pyobjc

I'm aware this might be a dumb question, but I can't figure out how to translate this simple Swift statement (didn't find an Objective-C example) into pyobjc:

```
let calendars = EventStore.calendars(for entityType:.Events)
```

What I got so far (trying out different options):

```
from EventKit import EKEventStore

ek_event_store = EKEventStore.alloc().init()
default_cal = ek_event_store.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()  # works, but not the calendar I wish to access

my_cal_identifier = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
my_cal = ek_event_store.calendar(my_cal_identifier))  # Error: 'EKEventStore' object has no attribute 'calendar'

calendars = ek_event_store.calendars()  # value is None. I don't know how to pass it the entityType
```

So I guess my problem is not knowing

- what the entityType is supposed to be (type? value?)
- how to pass the entityType to the **calendars** function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (using the dir function on the event store object and on a calendar object)

```
from EventKit import EKEventStore

ek_event_store = EKEventStore.alloc().init()

my_cal_identifier = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
my_cal = ek_store.calendarWithIdentifier_(cal_tcv_intern_id)

all_my_calendars = ek_store.calendarsForEntityType_(0)
```

I didn't find the Event types in the documentation, but with trial and error, I figured it out:

- 0: calendar
- 1: reminder

So I also gained some better insight how pyobjc is working:

`EventStore.calendars(for entityType:.Events)` becomes `EventStore.calendardsForEntityType(event_type)`.

I was also wondering why the "calendar" function could not be found, now I understand that it bacame **calendarWithIdentifier** in pyobjc.